# Determine all the integers that 0 divides

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I need some help with this task:

> Determine all the integers that 0 divides.

(This  question is about the divides relation, not about the arithmetic operation of division)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does it mean for one integer to divide another?

Comment: Mh, they might be found among the multiples of zero...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$0$ divides $0$ and nothing else.

For $0$ to divide $x$, there needs to be some multiple of $0$ that equals $x$, i.e. there needs to be some $y$ such that $0 \cdot y= x$. Since $0 \cdot y=0$ for any $y$, that means $x$ has to be $0$: nothing else works: so, $0$ does not divide anything other than $0$.

But, for $x=0$, $y=1$ will work just fine: $0 \cdot 1 = 0$. So, $0$ *does* divide $0$